# java.sql.SQLException from cassandra connection and querying with presto

Tags: java, cassandra, presto

I prepared some tables with cassandra using CQL. In fact, I tried to apply aggregation queries on my data (sum, avg, etc..). So, I used presto-cassandra with java. I have configured presto as follows:

**Config.properties:**

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri= `http://localhost:8080`
```

**JVM.properties:**

```
-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-XX:PermSize=150M
-XX:MaxPermSize=150M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150M
-Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Presto/lib/floatingdecimal-0.1.jar
```

**log.properties:**

```
com.facebook.presto=INFO
```

**node.properties:**

```
node.environment=production
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
node.data-dir=C:/Presto/data
```

**cassandra.properties:**

```
connector.name=cassandra
cassandra.contact-points=localhost
cassandra.native-protocol-port=9142
cassandra.thrift-port=9160
```

Then, I've been trying to connect to presto and run some queries through jdbc, but I keep getting errors. The code is :

```
public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");
    PrestoConnection connection = (PrestoConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:presto://localhost:8080/cassandra/premierkeys", "test","");
    PrestoStatement statement = (PrestoStatement) connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from client");
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }       
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    connect();
}
```

Also, the maven dependency looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
        <artifactId>presto-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>0.72</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
        <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.72</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`
```

But when I run this code I get:

```
***juil. 02, 2014 11:32:57 AM com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFOS: Logging initialized @122ms
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.executeQuery(PrestoStatement.java:54)
    at tester_cass.connect(tester_cass.java:19)
    at tester_cass.main(tester_cass.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response does not contain a JSON value
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.airlift.http.client.FullJsonResponseHandler$JsonResponse.getValue(FullJsonResponseHandler.java:148)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClient.<init>(StatementClient.java:82)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.QueryExecutor.startQuery(QueryExecutor.java:60)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoConnection.startQuery(PrestoConnection.java:541)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.executeQuery(PrestoStatement.java:49)
    ... 2***
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your question and gave it a slightly more descriptive title. In the opening, you mention that you tried some aggregation queries, but you don't explicitly state whether those were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the problem:

- try to run the Querys through the [Presto CLI](http://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html)
- get the stack trace from Presto on `http://<your-presto-coordinator>:8080/`